# Has anyone gotten Plan9 working in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

More than anything, I'm just curious to know if this is even possible, since [Plan 9](http://www.plan9.bell-labs.com/wiki/plan9/plan_9_wiki/) isn't in the [list of GuestOSes](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) on the VirtualBox website.

However, if someone out there *has* got it working, my specific question: Whenever I try to boot Plan9, either as a live cd or to install inside of VirtualBox, once the GUI loads all I get is a screen of garbage.  I think I've tried just about every graphics driver combination at startup - specifically, even 640x480x8 in VESA mode didn't work.

Any suggestions as to how I can load it?

Answer (score 2):

Definitely possible:

[image]

Although it requires a lot of tweaking apparently. From what I've read, it seems to be much more cooperative in [QEMU](http://www.nongnu.org/qemu/).